# Exercises for Spivak's Vol 2 "A comprehensive Introduction to differential geometry"

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

Looking through Spivak's Vol 2. of "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential geometry", I don't think there are any exercises. Is there a good source of supplementary exercises for Spivak's Differential Geometry?